# How Can I use If statement with relational operator in a SELECT statement in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, toad

I would like to know how to use if statement in a select statement in `MySQL` to do the following:

I have a table with 8 columns and i would like to change the values when creating a `view`. For example: i have a column named `Temperature`, i want to change values below `-50 to NULL` during `View` creation.

How can i do this using `IF` statement? or is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

The ANSI standard syntax is `case`:

```
select (case when temperature >= -50 then temperature end) as temperature
```

Without an `else` clause, the default is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `CASE`

```
CREATE 
/*[ALGORITHM = {UNDEFINED | MERGE | TEMPTABLE}]
    [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
    [SQL SECURITY { DEFINER | INVOKER }]*/
VIEW `db`.`test` AS 
(SELECT 
  col,
  col2,
  (
    CASE
      WHEN col3 < - 50 
      THEN NULL 
      ELSE col3 
    END
  ) col3 
FROM
  ...) ;
```